# How does Future's exec_ work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

How does this code, which forward-ports `exec`, work?

```
# Implementation of exec_ is from ``six``:
if PY3:
    import builtins
    exec_ = getattr(builtins, "exec")
else:
    def exec_(code, globs=None, locs=None):
        """Execute code in a namespace."""
        if globs is None:
            frame = sys._getframe(1)
            globs = frame.f_globals
            if locs is None:
                locs = frame.f_locals
            del frame
        elif locs is None:
            locs = globs
        exec("""exec code in globs, locs""")
```

The snippet is copied from [Python Future](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/521477b69e4148f720b2f0b6b5287e5947bff203/src/future/utils/__init__.py#L602) because I was too lazy to find [the original from Six](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/7aed6b9fba085a42cf5d948f0f0c0e39e7c2a740/six.py?at=default#cl-616) which Martijn Pieters linked to.

Answers specific to Six's (identical-bar `reraise`) version are welcome too.

Comment: Link to original: https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/7aed6b9fba085a42cf5d948f0f0c0e39e7c2a740/six.py?at=default#cl-616

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Python 3:

```
if PY3:
```

This is relatively straighforward:

```
    import builtins
    exec_ = getattr(builtins, "exec")
```

The reason to use `getattr` is that on Python 2 `exec` is a statment and you want to avoid:

```
>>> builtins.exec
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    builtins.exec
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Using a string to do lookup gets around the problem of `exec` not being a valid identifier.

If Python 2:

```
else:
```

We want to define `exec_` to be like `exec` on Python 3, which means it looks like so:

```
    def exec_(code, globs=None, locs=None):
        """Execute code in a namespace."""
```

Let's quickly check the docs:

```
help(exec)
#>>> Help on built-in function exec in module builtins:
#>>>
#>>> exec(...)
#>>>     exec(object[, globals[, locals]])
#>>>     
#>>>     Read and execute code from an object, which can be a string or a code
#>>>     object.
#>>>     The globals and locals are dictionaries, defaulting to the current
#>>>     globals and locals.  If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
#>>>
```

This should help explain the next part:

```
        if globs is None:
            frame = sys._getframe(1)
            globs = frame.f_globals
```

If `globs is None`, we want it to default to the globals *of the caller's scope*. This is actually quite involved.

First we *get the outer frame*:

```
import sys
help(sys._getframe)
#>>> Help on built-in function _getframe in module sys:
#>>>
#>>> _getframe(...)
#>>>     _getframe([depth]) -> frameobject
#>>>     
#>>>     Return a frame object from the call stack.  If optional integer depth is
#>>>     given, return the frame object that many calls below the top of the stack.
#>>>     If that is deeper than the call stack, ValueError is raised.  The default
#>>>     for depth is zero, returning the frame at the top of the call stack.
#>>>     
#>>>     This function should be used for internal and specialized
#>>>     purposes only.
#>>>
```

`sys._getframe` is just the caller's scope, then. A frame is the environment in which function execution happens, and stores several interesting properties such as `f_globals` - the globals from the point of view of that function.

Then if does:

```
            if locs is None:
                locs = frame.f_locals
```

to default `locs` to the locals.

The frame is deleted to prevent this from keeping things alive unnecessarily during the `exec` call.

```
            del frame
```

Penultimately,

```
        elif locs is None:
            locs = globs
```

which is to fufull the "If only globals is given, locals defaults to it." part.

Then the most fun part:

```
        exec("""exec code in globs, locs""")
```

Running just `exec code in globs, locs` would mean that when compiled on Python 3, this would error as `exec` is no longer a statement. Thus, an outer `exec("""exec code in globs, locs""")` call is made.

On Python 3, this will never be run but will *compile*. On Python 2, this will capture the locals `globs` and `locs`, allowing it to run `exec code in globs, locs`.

---

[*Please* do look at Antti Haapala's answer, though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26098101/1763356) as these shennanigans are actually made somewhat irrelevant by what he points out, including some information that Martijn Pieters brought forward.

Comment: Actually, the double exec within the `def exec_` is unnecessary: `exec (code) in globs, locs` with extra parenthesis around `code` does not result in `SyntaxError` in Python 3

Comment: And in Python 2, you can use `exec(code, globs, locs)` *just fine*; it is forward compatible with Python 3 out of the box.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you know what version introduced that?

Comment: @Veedrac: It has worked forever, because [back in 1993](https://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/fccd415e2eb8/Python/ceval.c#l2521) `exec` became a statement but the tuple form was kept for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The final `exec("""exec code in globs, locs""")` is indeed superfluous, the statement can be made to parse in Python 3 without `SyntaxError` by writing the code as

```
exec (code) in globs, locs
```

Which in python 2 will be parsed as

```
exec code in globs, locs
```

And in Python 3 it is effectively identical with

```
tuple([exec(code) in globs, locs])
```

---

However, the `exec` statement in Python has *always* been able to accept a *tuple* argument, so the `exec` line could be written as

```
exec(code, globs, locs)
```

Which would run identically in Python 2 and 3 or even

```
exec(tuple([code, globs, locs]))
```

(which works on Python 2 only); indeed the only thing one can do in Python 3 that is not possible in Python 2 and why this wrapper would be needed would be to make it a true function/method object, that can be assigned to another name or passed as an argument, as currently

```
exec_ = exec
```

is `SyntaxError` in Python 2.

---

Similarly in Python 3,

```
print argument, argument, argument,
```

is a syntax error, but in polyglotting code one can always contain

```
if PY2:
    print >> sys.stdout, argument, argument, argument,
```

which will in Python 3 be parsed as

```
tuple([print >> sys.stdout, argument, argument, argument])
```